# functional equation knowing monotony

Tags: calculus

Determine the functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ which have a primitive $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ with the next properties:

i) $F(x)\geqslant f(x)\geqslant0 ,\forall x\in \mathbb R$

ii) $\exists x_0\in \mathbb R$ such that $F(x_0)=0$

I got that $F$ is ascending and $F(x)=0 ,\forall x\le x_0$. I don't know what to do after... can somebody help me, please?

Comment: My try was $f(x)=logx  $, F(x) is integral of logx  = $x (logx-1)$. But it isnt correct , F is smaler than f for x=1 for example. Also $e^x$ comes to mind but it doesnt fullfil second rule

Answer (score 1):

We can find that for every $x$,
$$
\left(e^{-x}F(x)\right)'=e^{-x}\left(f(x)-F(x)\right)\le 0,
$$ i.e. $e^{-x}F(x)$ is decreasing. Since $e^{-x}F(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$, we have that for every $x\ge x_0$, $e^{-x}F(x) =0$, i.e. $F(x) =0$.

On the other hand, we have $F'(x) = f(x)\ge 0$ for every $x$, implying that $F$ is increasing. This gives $F(x) =0$ for every $x\le x_0$.

Summing these up, we conclude that $F(x) \equiv 0$, hence $f(x) = F'(x) \equiv 0$.